# Flutter: Firestore helper returns nothing

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to geo query with [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firestore_helpers) but it returns nothing.

I set data to `Firestore` like so

```
var lat = 34.702485;
var lng = 135.495951;
Firestore.instance.collection('helper').document('abc').setData({'location': new GeoPoint(lat, lng), 'name': 'Osaka Station'});
```

And fetching like so.

```
 Stream<List<Item>> itemsStream() {
    return getDataInArea(
      source: Firestore.instance.collection('helper'), 
      area: Area(place, 20.0), 
      locationFieldNameInDB: 'location',
      mapper: (document) {
        print(document.exists);
        print(document.data);
      },
      // serverSideOrdering: [new OrderConstraint('timeStamp', false)],
    );
  }
```

This returns nothing and I set breakpoint, this function ends at area it won't go further.
Does anyone know what am I missing?

Comment: Have you considered using the official firestore plugin?

Comment: Are you sure the `Future` returned by `setData` is completed before you re-read the data?

Comment: Yeah after data was created successfully, I called itemStream.